# Unity3d saved as prefab, readding removes meshes

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity3d I found the feature of saving GameObjects through dragging them from the Hierarchy into the Assets Folder. I'm using this to test stuff in a different scene.
Strangely, I it doesn't work with this one properly:
[image: original object]

after readding it, all meshes are missing:
[image: right:reimported one, left:original]

1. Do you know how to fix this?
2. Is there a possibility to move gameObjects, maybe through code, from one scene to another one(in editor)?

Comment: If you want to reuse gameObjects in multiple Scenes it is always recommended to do this with Prefabs. -  If you readd the Prefab to the Scene where you created it, is it still broken?

Comment: yes, it is still broken

Comment: you could try reassigning the meshes in inspector, apply the changes to the prefab, delete it from the scene , save the scene.  - Had this problem myself and this did work sometimes

Comment: I already feared having to do this, because there are about 50 meshes at this model :/

Comment: Are you saving your prefabs when you change them? using the "save" button int he inspector?

Comment: I drag them in the Asset folder and delete the old one

Answer (score 1):

2. It is possible to move GameObject from one scene to another by using [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html), if you need to do so in runtime.

Comment: Nice, do you know how to apply it in the editor (not in runtime) ?